# What does living creature mean?

Tags: animals

Does the Hebrew word 'nephesh' (נֶפֶשׁ) refer to any creature (animal or human) or just humans? What does it actually mean in Hebrew? I see it is used in Bereshit to describe the living 'creatures' created on day 5 and day 6 referring to sea life, birds and animals. My translation of nephesh says it means a breathing creature and that figuratively it could mean soul, appetite, emotion desire, person. But that understanding would then mean that Adam and Eve were not the only humans created?

I have also heard it argued that the living creatures created on day 6 were not only animals (the four footed kind) but animalistic humans, i.e. another race of human beings separate from Adam, and that is how people multiplied on the earth, and that it was from this race that the sons of God (Adam's race) went into when the Scripture says they went into the daughters of men and bore children who became known as the Nephilim.

Which could explain why God in Bereshit 2: 18,19 when HE said it is not good for adam to be alone, that a suitable helper should be made for him, formed the 'חַיַּ֤ת' of the field and brought them to adam to see what he would call each חַיָּ֖ה nephesh. How would animals be a suitable helper to man unless these חַיַּ֤ת that is referred to are not animals but another race of humanity?